# Spring-integration-file : inbound-channel-adapter with use-watch-service="true" and watch-events="CREATE,DELETE", are delete events well managed?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm using spring-integration-file (last release 4.3.4.RELEASE) to watch on a directory and get messages on CREATE and DELETE events.

Here is my Spring config :

```
<int:channel id="canalFichiersFTP" />
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="integrateurFichiersFTP" directory="#{gestionnaireChemins.cheminRepertoireEntrant}"
    use-watch-service="true" channel="canalFichiersFTP" auto-create-directory="false" watch-events="CREATE,DELETE">
    <int:poller id="pollerFichiersFTP" fixed-delay="${trt001.delai.verification.ftp}" />
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
<int:service-activator input-channel="canalFichiersFTP" ref="trt001Scheduler" method="recevoirNouveauFichierFTP" />
```

I add the use-watch-service="true" (as explained in spring doc http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html#watch-service-directory-scanner) to use the FileReadingMessageSource.WatchServiceDirectoryScanner and watch-events="CREATE,DELETE" to get messages when a new file is created in the directory and to get a message when a file is deleted and created again.

But it does'nt work, when I create a file in the directory I get a message, but when I delete the file and create it again I don't get a message, if I well understood the doc I should receive one.

This watch service uses two filters AcceptOnceFileListFilter and IgnoreHiddenFileListFilter gathered in one CompositeFileListFilter. On the DELETE event the WatchServiceDirectoryScanner should call the remove method on the CompositeFileListFilter (which is a ResettableFileListFilter and will call the remove method on the AcceptOnceFileListFilter) but it doesn't.

I think the issue is on line 501 of FileReadingMessageSource.java file, I don't understand why the instanceof comparison is done on FileReadingMessageSource.this.filter and not this.filter, but maybe I miss something ? FileReadingMessageSource.this.filter is null at runtime and then no remove call is made on the filter, I think that's the reason why the AcceptOnceFileListFilter doesn't receive the remove call and why when I delete the file and create it again my code does'nt receive the message (the AcceptOnceFileListFilter considers I already received it).

Please help me, is it a bug in spring code, an error in my config or maybe I misunderstood something in the spring doc ?

Many thx for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug; usually the two filter references are the same but, as you say, with your configuration the source filter is null.

I will open a JIRA issue; the work around is to explicitly set `ignore-hidden="true"` and the parser will add the filter properly.

[JIRA here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4147).